# How to terminate ANY process using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, pid, kill

Node does not seem to have a system call to kill a process (given I know its PID), or does it?

If there is no built-in function for this, what is a valid cross-platform approach?

Comment: Nodejs has a [process.kill()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processkillpid-signal) method that you can use to kill a process by pid.

Comment: @TGrif That's good stuff! The `terminate` library also uses `process.kill` under the hood, but it also deals with some processes needing more than one kill signal, and makes sure that all children are killed as well.

Answer (score 0):

[The terminate library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terminate) has seemingly been built for this purpose. It is cross-platform. (I tried it on Windows and MAC.)

[Here is a working sample](https://github.com/Domiii/port-pid-and-terminate).
It also illustrates how to find PID by PORT.

Example:

```js
const { promisify } = require('util');
/**
 * NOTE: as of 2021, terminate is still callback-based.
 */
const terminate = promisify(require('terminate'));

await terminate(myPid);

console.log('Process terminated.');
```

Note that if the process does not exist (or in case of any other problems), it will throw, so you might want to `try/catch` correspondingly.